# How to do a progress bar with job (Jenkins)

Tags: javascript, jenkins

I don't know how can I create a progress bar for my job when they are building.

For example, I have 5 jobs : toto, titi, tata, trtr and tztz

When toto is in build, my progress bar need to be at 20%

Then titi is in build, 40%

Then tata is in build, 60%

Then trtr is in build, 80%

And tztz is in build, 100%

For the moment, I have only display the job and the order of my job:

```
function getDataAjax(param) {
var oXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// construction de l'url avec le paramètre
var url = "https://.../job/"+param+"/api/json?pretty=true";  
oXhr.open('GET', url, true);
oXhr.onload = function() {
    // récup. des données sous forme d'un objet
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var Data = data.downstreamProjects.map(function(group) {    

    if (group.name) {
    console.log(group.name);
    // rappel avec nouveau paramètre
    getDataAjax(group.name);

    }

}) 

};
oXhr.send(null);

}
// 1st appel
getDataAjax("toto");

// OUTPUT 
/* toto
   titi
   tata
   trtr
   tztz
```

I know that the first param is toto and thanks to the DownStreamProject, I can display the next job :

toto->titi->tata->trtr->tztz

I just don't know how can I start for my progress bar ...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to create a progressbar : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp

Just get the status of your jobs and update the progressbar if the job is building/running.

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: What do you mean by status and how can I determinate if the job is building ?

Comment: Sorry I dont have acces to my Jenkins to give you a clear answer, but you can check if there's some status property in the json result. If not, get the **lastBuild** for that job and check the **result** and the date of the build to determine if the job has run.

Comment: Don't say sorry it's ok ;). 
I don't see a specific status property in my JSON but I can get the lastBuild for a job, I have a result "SUCESS" and got also timestamp and estimeDuration.
But How can I create a progress bar with this value ?

Comment: By adding conditions on the timestamp being greater than the "upstream" project, for exemple. If **titi** has a greater timestimp than **toto** you add 20% to your progress bar. It's a bit of a hacky solution.

Comment: If I understand, for example, toto timestamp is 1551164100895 and titi timestamp is 1551164985234. You mean is titi has a greater timestamp than toto, so i need to grow up the progress bar ?

Comment: Yes, it means that the last build of titi has run after the build of toto, so logically you your build chain has progressed and you should update the progressbar. If in the other case the timestamp of titi is smaller, it means it's an older build. The new one hasn't started yet.

Comment: Be aware that this logic will obviously not work for you, if there are parallel build on those jobs.